# How can I add JDK 1.8.0_161 to IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I installed IntelliJ IDEA and the latest Java (1.8.0_161), which I downloaded from Oracle, to my new Mac (10.13.3).

**How can I add JDK 1.8.0_161 to IntelliJ IDEA?**
**Where is my jdk1.8.0_161 folder?**

I thank you in advance.

1. JDK 1.8.0_161 was not found inIntelliJ IDEA.

[image: JDK 1.8.0_161 was not found inIntelliJ IDEA.]

2. Java seems to be properly installed.

[image: Java seems to be properly installed.]

3. I went to that path, but failed to find jdk1.8.0_161 folder.

[image: I went to that path, but failed to find jdk1.8.0_161 folder.]

4. It seems that my mac only has 1.6.0.

[image: It seems that my mac only has 1.6.0.]

5. I checked the version and my java is still 1.6.0.

[image: I checked the version and my java is still 1.6.0.]

Comment: Regarding screenshot №2: make sure you have installed the **JDK**, not **JRE**. Install page: [JDK 9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html) , [JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Open the Project Structure dialog (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).

Step 2. In the leftmost panel, under Platform Settings, click SDKs.

Step 3. Above the pane to the right, click new and select JDK.

Step 4. In the dialog that opens, select the installation directory of the JDK to be used and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Java's auto update removed JDK, re install [Java SE Development Kit 8u162](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u162-b12/0da788060d494f5095bf8624735fa2f1/jdk-8u162-windows-x64.exe)